# Identifying where Remark column changes in R data.frame based on time stamp

Tags: r

I have a data set:

```
ID <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3)

Remarks<-c("joined","joined","newrole","newrole","transferred","transferred","joined","newrole",            "transferred","joined","joined","newrole","newrole","transferred")

Date<-c("2020/08/01 06:31:38","2020/08/01 06:31:38","2020/08/01 13:17:07",
        "2020/08/01 13:17:07","2020/08/01 13:29:01","2020/08/01 13:29:01",
        "2020/08/03 06:31:38","2020/08/04 06:31:38","2020/08/04 13:17:07",
         "2020/08/07 13:17:07","2020/08/07 13:29:01","2020/08/07 13:29:01",
         "2020/08/07 13:17:07","2020/08/10 13:29:01")

d <- data.frame(ID, Remarks, Date)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
d <- data.frame(ID, Remarks, Date, stringsAsFactors = F)
d %>% filter(Remarks != lag(Remarks, default = ''))
```

Output:

```
  ID     Remarks                Date
1  1      joined 2020/08/01 06:31:38
2  1     newrole 2020/08/01 13:17:07
3  1 transferred 2020/08/01 13:29:01
4  2      joined 2020/08/03 06:31:38
5  2     newrole 2020/08/04 06:31:38
6  2 transferred 2020/08/04 13:17:07
7  3      joined 2020/08/07 13:17:07
8  3     newrole 2020/08/07 13:29:01
9  3 transferred 2020/08/10 13:29:01
```

Comment: Thank you is there any possibility that two make each subset into different tables/data frame   like all joined into one data frame,all new role into one data frame

Comment: yes, it is possible, you can use `filter(Remarks == 'joined')`

Answer (score 1):

We can use `data.table`s `rleidv`/`rleid` to select only the rows where `Remark` changes.

```
d[!duplicated(data.table::rleid(d$Remarks)), ]
#Or with rleidv
#d[!duplicated(data.table::rleidv(d, cols = 'Remarks')), ]

#   ID     Remarks                Date
#1   1      joined 2020/08/01 06:31:38
#3   1     newrole 2020/08/01 13:17:07
#5   1 transferred 2020/08/01 13:29:01
#7   2      joined 2020/08/03 06:31:38
#8   2     newrole 2020/08/04 06:31:38
#9   2 transferred 2020/08/04 13:17:07
#10  3      joined 2020/08/07 13:17:07
#12  3     newrole 2020/08/07 13:29:01
#14  3 transferred 2020/08/10 13:29:01
```